# Calling HAML within Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Javascript. In my new function of my controller is as follows:

```
def new
   @student = Student.new

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html # which is by default new.html.haml
      format.json  { render :json=> @student }
end
```

In my new.html.haml I just want to add a form that only takes roll number of a student and if the student already exists then clicking the submit button will take me to another form where the fields will be already filled with the existing student's info and I can edit them if I want and otherwise the same form will appear where I have to enter all the info of the new student.

Here my problem is that, I cannot decide how I manipulate the clicking the submit button in the haml form, that is based on the student's existence. I was thinking of using javascript here but then I have to call the haml that contains all the other fields related to the student, within the javascript, I don't know if that is possible or not. I have not found any documents talking about calling haml inside javascript.

I am clueless how to proceed. Please help.

**EDIT** : Here I forgot to mention one thing that submission of the latter form should redirect me to the create function and update function of students_controller depending upon the student's existence. Will it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to follow your question but I'll try answer it anyway. :-)

New is normally for creating a new instance. Maybe you should name it find or something like that. Than in the controller for find do something like:

```
def find
  student = Student.find_by_roll_number params[:roll_number]
  if student
    redirect_to edit_student_path(student)
  else
    redirect_to new_student_path
  end
end
```

No need for javascript unless you don't want the server roundtrip.